# Create page after login xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm an XCode noob and I've looked all over for the answer. This is my first time building anything in XCode and I've created a login window using Firebase in ViewController.swift. Once the user is logged in, I want them to go to another screen that is using MapKit etc. How do I automatically link the login window success to the second page?

I've created a new cocoa touch class file as MapViewController.swift - do I just call the map function at the end of the login function or is there a more simple way to do it with the storyboard?

Sorry for the stupid question

Comment: Essentially, you create another view controller and then transition to that one. But this isn't the right place to ask such a broad question. I suggest looking into the *tons* of available tutorials to get started :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after you check that the user enters the right credentials set function  to call the new view controller

```
func transition() {   
    let mapViewController:MapViewController = MapViewController()

    self.presentViewController(mapViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

 }
```

then call it

```
transition()
```

Comment: This is only correct, if the OP is not using a NavigationController.

Comment: Okay so I'll add this after the authentication. Where does the ```SecondViewController``` name fit into this? As I understand it, I name my function in the MapViewController ```transition``` or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: Cannot find type 'MapViewController' in scope it says. My file name is MapViewController but the class name is mapViewController. Once that is fixed, where and how exactly do I call the ```transition()``` function?

Comment: you have the first view controller contain: login view and, function and transition function.      The second view controller contains a map kit and I named it MapViewController

Comment: you can share code here https://codeshare.io/2KV1vE

Comment: Hey @MohammedHassan - could you please check out my new post? I'm having trouble adding a text/search field and button onto that mapviewcontroller